# regex for list of ip addresses

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, validation

I want to match a string containing either '*' or a comma separated list of IPv4 addresses.

The following works for one IP or a star:

> /^(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|*)$/

And I've tried to adopt this for having a list of IPs or a star:

> /^(?:^|, )(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|*)$/

But it doesn't works as expected.

Could you please help me?

thx,
Thomas

Comment: I take it you only want to match IPv4?

Comment: It would be great, if you could provide sample input, expected and real output for your attempts. Making a fiddle would be even better.

Comment: `*` is a special character, so you have to escape it like `\*` if you want to find it inside a string (your IP Adress). I'm not sure if this is the only problem, so I didn't post that as an answer.

Comment: well, I want to match either the star, so I need to escape it via \* or a list of IPv4 addresses like: "127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2,123.123.123.123"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you were being specific about the accepted numbers for the *IPs*,

```
/^\*$|^(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}(?:\s*,\s*(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3})*$/
// * or   IP=   0-255                    .0-255 (3 more times)           then (, IP) 0 or mote times
```

I'd only use a *RegExp* like this if you **must** check validity with just one *RegExp*, because it may be much clearer to break it down into several steps, otherwise.

```
// some func
var reIP = /^(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}$/,
    tokens = str.split(/\s*,\s*/), i;
for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i)
    if (!reIP.test(tokens[i]))
        return false;
return true;
```

Comment: thx for sharing. But this regex doesn't allow a more than 2 digits starting at second octet of the IP address. What could be wrong there? e.g.: /^\*$|^(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3}(?:\s*,\s*(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]){3})*$/.test "192.168.1.1"
false

Comment: Of course, I could do it that way and was shortly thinking about doing so, too. But for this project it's better doing the check via a regex.

Comment: Oh I forgot a grouping